# Is the book "Gettings Started with Julia Programming" Balbaert 2015 out of date?

Tags: julia

I have just began learning Julia and I would like to confirm whether the book *Getting Started with Julia Programming* (2015) by Ivo Balbaert is out of date (with respect to Julia 1.8.1).

I am trying to work through the book but have noticed the following inconsistencies.

1. function `linspace` appears to be degraded in favor of `linRange`
2. book shows the following syntax for creating an array of 10 elements arr4 = [1:10]. This creates an array length 1 that contains a range of length 10 hence the slicing example they give arr4[1:4] does not work it must be arr4[1][1:4]
3. I am trying to follow the example given for array concatenation but it does not work

[image]

When correcting for the brackets to create array b I get an error that appears to be caused by different types. Array b is `UnitRange{Int64}` while c is `Vector{Int64}`. This can be rectified by using `collect(1:7)` to make the range 1:7 into a vector.

[image]

The above inconsistencies are all in Chapter 2. I do not have page numbers as I am using a pdf.

Hopefully, listing these inconsistencies will help someone else who finds themselves similarly confused when trying to learn Julia.

Could someone point me to a better reference for learning Julia (preferably a book).

Thank you for your help.
NicoFish

Comment: Definitely out of date. 2015 is very very early days of Julia, far before its version 1.0 which generally marks that the syntax and semantics have been stabilized. So there were several changes to the syntax between 2015 and the final 1.0 syntax.  You check out https://julialang.org/learning/books/ for more current and up-to-date books.

Comment: Also, StackOverflow frowns on this type of question (which are suggestion/recommendation based), and your question will probably be closed at some point. You can take a look at https://discourse.julialang.org/ for more free form discussion.

Comment: Get my Aoress book :-) No, kkidding... for Julia itself any book referring to Julia >= 1.0 is fine, altought one important element of Julia is its package ecosystem, and that evolved even more recently, with many important packages reaching v1.0 in 2021 or 2022.. so even my book of 2019 for the parts referring to the main packages is already obsolete.

Comment: For the examples with array creation you can write `[1:10;]` instead of `[1:10]`. Note that while language is somewhat stable since 1.0, the API of many libraries has changed. Basically when using even Julia 1.0 book around 30-40% of examples will not work anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, 2015 is outdated these days. Version 1.0 was released in 2018, and many important changes happened up to that point. After v1.0, though, Julia is quite stable, and a book released later than that may still be useful after 7 years. It will probably be missing some of the newer features, though.

As to your specific remarks

- `linspace` has been replaced by `range` (which can do more things), or with `LinRange`, which is more low-level, but which may have lower numerical accuracy.
- I'm pretty sure `[1:10]` did *not* produce a `Vector{Int}`, even in 2015. This must be a typo, it should probably be `[1:10;]`.

I'm not able to recommend any particular book, since I haven't read any of them, but there is a list of books here: https://julialang.org/learning/books/ I notice that Ivo Baelbert wrote one in 2018 called "Julia 1.0 Programming". I don't know how good it is.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the aforementioned book was written way before Julia v1.0 was even branches, so it's syntax is very different from modern Julia. I would not recommend it unless someone is interested in learning the historical Julia v0.3 (current version is v1.7, with major syntactic changes in 0.4, 0.5, 0.6 and 1.0)